# ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings.py' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named py

Tags: python, django, geodjango

Shis is the error I am getting while I'm trying to import models from django.contrib.gis.db using following command

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
```

I want to do this to define geographic model.
I am getting the below mentioned error.

Guys plz help me out.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.db.models import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings.py' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named py
```

This is the full traceback I'm getting in the terminal.

Answer (score 10):

Somewhere you're doing `import settings.py` instead of `import settings`.